# Good practices using listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, listener

recently I started programming simple server that is receiving emails and saving it to database. I wanted to split code to be more readable and maintainable, so I came up with such structure:

```
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
const listener = new MyEmitter();

databaseHandlerInit(listener);
emailHandlerInit(listener);
requestsHandlerInit(listener);
```

Database handler is connecting to database, saving, modifying data. Email handler is responsible for recieving and sending emails and requests handler is an express server.

I'm curious if something like this is considered as "bad programming practice":

```
// requestsHandler
router.post("/api", (req, res) => {
 listener.emit("doSomethingInDatabase", req, res);
});
```

Listener is emitting an event to `databaseHandlerInit` which handles database stuff. It's working fine because listener has mongoose object in his local scope. `emailHandlerInit` is working the same way. I feel like it could be done better and more professional. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Let's start buy explaining _why_ you came to the conclusion Events are the way to go here

Comment: @Itamar as I said, listener in databaseHandler has access to local scope of function, which means it has access to currently connected database methods.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you don't want to call these methods directly?

Comment: @Itamar How can I call these methods directly if they are in local scope of different function? I wanted to split my server.js code into smaller chunks instead of writing everyting in one file. That's why I used even listeners, to make code more readable.

Comment: You can export / import between files